# Change cursor style when hovered over google chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, mousehover

I have a google chart which takes you to a different page when clicked. I would like to change the cursor style when hovered over the chart to indicate that its clickable. I am listening to the `onmouseover` event and i have this code in the handler

```
$('#div_id path').css("cursor", "pointer")
```

I can see the style applied to the path elements. But the cursor doesn't change. How do i change the cursor style when hovered on google chart?

Comment: Can you show your html div elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with just CSS:

```
#chart element { cursor: pointer; }
```

Otherwise try using `.css('cursor', 'pointer')` on the selector you are listening for the `mouseover` event on and removing the `mouseover` call.

Answer (score 5):

You could just add a style looks like :

```
#chart_div g g g rect {
    cursor: pointer
}
```

[example google chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Example)

<kbd>[Demo CssDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/dve3f8ty)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This is working pretty well for me.

```
.chart path { cursor: pointer; }
```